# How to center Grid RecyclerView items?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a recycler view using grid layout manager. I did my item view to have the witdh = match_parent to make my items to have equal width depending on the screen width. But there is also constraint which is max width for my item view. So, if the span count is small, all my items are aligned by the left, but I want those items to be aligned by the center.

Examples: [image: 1]

In case 1, everything is ok.
In case 2, items are not centered. P.S. I tried layout_gravity = center, gravity = center, it does not help

Comment: Try changing column in GridLayoutManager from 5 to 3

Comment: i change span count dynamically

Comment: Do you want your views packed in the center, or distributed evenly to fill the full width of the screen?

Comment: Please add your xml and initializing your RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/question_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f0f4fd" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have personally used that put your recycler view in a layout then make it as center,

Answer (score 0):

In the row's xml, it is necessary to align the elements to the center

Answer (score 0):

In your item layout, don't use `wrap_content`, or a fixed size, in `layout_width`.
You should use `match_parent` as `layout_width`.